# How do I stop inserting from inputs to an array of strings when a particular string is encountered in a C program?

Tags: c, string, function, pointers, multidimensional-array

I have a function that reads one string from input and inserts into an array is used to loop through the input strings to insert in an array of strings. However if a string == "readuntilthisline", the loop breaks. The function I have written still adds the string to the array. Any way I can stop reading that string? This is how my function looks:

```
typedef char String[300];
int main() {
    String strings[10];
    int string_number=0;
    function(strings,&string_number);
    return 0;
}

void function(String strings[], int *string_number){
    int i=0;
    while (read_one_string(strings[*string_number],300) == 1) {
            if (strncmp(strings[i],"readuntilthisline") == 0){
                    break;
            }
            *string_number+=1;
            i++;
    }
}

//The read_one_string function reads one string at a time from input using getchar and returns 1 if last character read is not EOF.
```

Comment: You could read the string into a temporary variable and add it to the array after the comparison

Comment: I am new to C, can you tell me what do I need to add to the function for that?

Comment: Just to clarify,  your code works except the string `"readuntilthisline"` is also added right?

Comment: @AbhayAravinda Yes

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, this should work. However, the variable `i` is most probably redundant and you should be able to manage with using only string_number.

```
void function(String strings[], int *string_number){
    int i=0;
    String temp;
    while (read_one_string(temp,300) == 1) {
            if (strncmp(temp,"readuntilthisline") == 0){
                    break;
            }
            strcpy(strings[*string_number],temp);
            *string_number+=1;
            i++;
    }
}
```